# Passing variables and values from an R script to a shell script

Tags: r, parsing

I'm working with a shell script(#!/bin/sh) and I wanted to know if there is a way to call variables with their values from an Rscript that I have called in my Shell script.
If that doesn't make sense I want to create, for example a data frame 
`data=data.frame(a=seq(1,5), b=seq(1,5))` in a script called **test.r**
and then call that variable, with it's content in my shell script, i.e to print it with an echo:

`echo $data`

Comment: About the first part of your question: why do not environment variables and `Sys.getenv()` work?

Answer (score 1):

The Bash feature you want is called command substitution, e.g:

```
echo $(./test.r)
```

That will echo the output of your Rscript. Alternatively you could capture it in an environment variable.

Comment: Yeah there is a library in R that does exactly that, I found about it yesterday, but I'll try it

Comment: Or save it to a temporary file. Depends on what you want to do with it.